# Recommendation Engines Test data

Tags: artificial-intelligence, recommendation-engine, test-data

I've started learning of recommendation systems theory and I want to start practice. But unfortunately, I've faced with next problem : I want test my code on some big data set (size around 100 MB - 1 GB) and I didn't find any open sources for such data. Also, I found few test data generators, but I want find some example of "real life data", instead of purely artificial data.

Where can I find such data sets?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try datasets from this https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne Thank you a lot! Seems, it's something which I've looked for.